# multicharacter strings to netcdf with python netCDF4

Tags: python, string, netcdf

The minimal example below shows how I'm trying to write strings to a netcdf file. The single character strings work as expected (var1). From the multi character strings (var2), however, only the first characters are taken into account.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

strs1 = ['a', 'b']
strs2 = ['aa', 'bb']

ds = Dataset('test.nc','w')
ds.createDimension('x', 2)
var1 = ds.createVariable('var1', 'S1', (u'x',))
var1[:] = strs1
print strs1,var1[:]
var2 = ds.createVariable('var2', 'S1', (u'x',))
var2[:] = strs2
print strs2,var2[:]
ds.close()
```

The output looks like this

```
['a', 'b'] ['a' 'b']
['aa', 'bb'] ['a' 'b']
```

I have tried to add a second dimension, but that does also not give the desired result.
Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

EDIT: using the first answer, I can get it working as follows, using a second dimension

```
import netCDF4
import numpy as np

strs1 = ['a', 'b']
strs2 = ['aa', 'bb']

ds = netCDF4.Dataset('test.nc','w')
ds.createDimension('x', 2)
ds.createDimension('strlen', 2)
var1 = ds.createVariable('var1', 'S1', (u'x',))
var1[:] = strs1
print strs1,var1[:]
var2 = ds.createVariable('var2', 'S1', (u'x',u'strlen'))
var2[:] = netCDF4.stringtochar(np.array(strs2))
print strs2,netCDF4.chartostring(var2[:])
ds.close()
```

Giving this output:

```
['a', 'b'] ['a' 'b']
['aa', 'bb'] ['aa' 'bb']
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a relative newbie to netCDF4 but when dealing with strings I've used the netCDF4 utility methods `netCDF4.stringtochar(strs2) and netCDF.chartostring(strs2`)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add a second dimension, just change 'S1' to 'S2'. If you want to use even longer strings with N characters, use 'SN'.